# Extend objects using functional invocation pattern. How?

Tags: javascript

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rhodee/4NKVH/

I've been reading the Crockford book and was wondering what is a proven approach to prying open the base constructor object and adding a function to it that child objects can access?

I thought I could access the prototype of my object and it appears that is not possible given my current code.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors:

- Your constructor function returns a totally unrelated object. Don't do that. Return `this`. (If no `return` statement exists, the constructor does this implicitly)
- Superconstructor calls are not very intuitive in JS. You need the ugly construct `MySuperclass.call(this, arg1, arg2, ...);`, so in your case `mammal.call(this, spec);` in the `cat` class
- You need the `new` keyword to instantiate an object that uses the prototype chain.

See http://jsfiddle.net/4NKVH/5/ for a fixed version of your code.